# SQLServer Transaction error when called from python

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I'm facing an incredibly puzzling situation, we have a recently updated SQL Server from 2016 to 2019, on which a stored procedure usually called from a python script after some data integration, now fails with an error.

> "[25000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot roll back TR_NL. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found. (6401)

The stored procedure itself follows a quite standard TRY/CATCH structure

```
USE [MYBASE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_myproc] 
    @error NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'Success' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @idMarche;
DECLARE @TranName VARCHAR(20);

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'SOME_TABLE')
BEGIN 
    SELECT @TranName = 'TR_NL';
    BEGIN TRANSACTION @TranName;
    BEGIN TRY
        /*
            Bunch of updates, inserts etc. Some of which conditionals with nested IF BEGIN END etc.
        */
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @error ='Error Number: ' + ISNULL(CAST(ERROR_NUMBER() AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NA')     + '; ' + Char(10) + 
                    'Error Severity '   + ISNULL(CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NA')   + '; ' + Char(10) +
                    'Error State '      + ISNULL(CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NA')      + '; ' + Char(10) +
                    'Error Line '       + ISNULL(CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NA')       + '; ' + Char(10) +
                    'Error Message '    + ISNULL(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'NA')
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TranName;
    END CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION @TranName;
END

/*
    A few more similar blocks of conditional transactions
*/

IF @error = 'Success' OR @error IS NULL
BEGIN
    /*
        Drop some tables
    */
END
END
```

Following call works perfectly well in SSMS but fails with said error when sent from my python script

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @return_value INTEGER;
DECLARE @error NVARCHAR(MAX);
EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[p_myproc] @error = @error OUTPUT;
SELECT  @error AS erreur, @return_value AS retour;
```

Comment: The error could be raised if the procedure rolls back while executed in a parent/outer transaction: https://dbfiddle.uk/RrzZ4djN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Python be default runs all commands in a transaction, unless you set `autocommit=true`. This means it is trying to roll back your transaction, but your error handler has done that already.

Your error handler is in any case flawed in a number of ways:

- As mentioned, it doesn't handle nested transactions well.
- It swallows exceptions, then selects the error message. This means that the client side code is not recognizing that an exception has occurred.
- If there were multiple errors at the same time (common with `DBCC` and `BACKUP` commands) then only one is returned.

Instead, just use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` at the top of your procedure, if you need to do any cleanup, make sure to re-throw the original exception using `THROW;`. Do **not** rollback the transaction, it will be rolled back automatically.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_myproc]
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'SOME_TABLE')
    BEGIN 
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            /*
                Bunch of updates, inserts etc. Some of which conditionals with nested IF BEGIN END etc.
            */
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END;

    /*
        A few more similar blocks of conditional transactions
    */

    /*
        Drop some tables
    */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- do cleanup. Do NOT rollback
    ;
    THROW;   -- rethrows the original exception
END CATCH;
```

If no cleanup is needed then do not use a `CATCH` at all. `XACT_ABORT` will rollback the transaction anyway.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_myproc]
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;


IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'SOME_TABLE')
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        /*
            Bunch of updates, inserts etc. Some of which conditionals with nested IF BEGIN END etc.
        */
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END

/*
    A few more similar blocks of conditional transactions
*/

/*
    Drop some tables
*/
```

See also the following links

- [How to use SET XACT_ABORT ON the right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849710/how-to-use-set-xact-abort-on-the-right-way/69854045#69854045)
- [What is the point of TRY CATCH block when XACT_ABORT is turned ON?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306846/what-is-the-point-of-try-catch-block-when-xact-abort-is-turned-on/306870#306870)
- [Using multiple relating statements inside a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375519/using-multiple-relating-statements-inside-a-stored-procedure/69383715#69383715)

Comment: Thanks for that extensive answer, I will examine your suggestions carefully .